# Start service on boot: why it doens't work?

Tags: java, android, service

I would like to start a service when the phone boot but does not work and I do not understand why. In my Package i created a class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

    public class BootPhone extends BroadcastReceiver{

        Intent intent;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }

    }
```

My Service.class is

```
public class Service extends Service{

    Notify notify;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        notify = new Notify(this);
    }

}
```

In my Manifest i put

```
<service android:name="Servicer"></service>
    <receiver android:name="BootPhone"
                android:enabled="true"
                        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But, why it does'n work? Where is the problem/error?

Comment: if my ans is working mark it as correct by ticking it ...so that other having same problem may easily find the solution

Answer (score 2):

you have to declare user permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```